# (wx)Maxima: how to extract (only) the value from `solve`?

Tags: equation, maxima, wxmaxima

I'm trying to find the roots of relatively simple polynomial expressions, programmatically.

I found `solve(expr, var)` returns a list of equations that satisfy `expr` and found that using `args` on this list elements will list `[var, val_i]` and was wondering if this is the most direct approach?

I tried `allroots` but I get an error "not a polynomial" for anything I tried plugging in, whether an expression or an equation (*e.g.* I tried `var + 8`; `var+8 = 0`; `var^2 + 16` *etc*.).

Comment: Try `rhs(mysolution[k])` to get the k-th value, where `mysolution` is whatever was returned by `solve`. (`rhs` = right-hand side, see also `lhs` = left-hand side.)

Comment: What was the exact input for `allroots`? When I try the examples you mentioned, I get a valid result.